# MarkLogic: Loading (import) XQuery Modules from database

Tags: module, xquery, marklogic

I want to load a module which is stored in a database under the modules named as **"/modules/mylib.xqy"**.

Currently, in the document requiring these module, I am writing

```
import module namespace rb2lib="http://example.com/modules/lib" at "/modules/mylib.xqy";
```

Unfortunately, this expression makes a lookup on the filesystem and not on my database. 
Is there a way loading modules stored in database?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, change the application server configuration's `modules` setting from `(file system)` to the Modules database (or any database). The XQuery module must be stored in that database, and its URI must be the app server's `module root` plus the import location. For example, you could set your module root to `/` and store the module at `/modules/mylib.xqy`.

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by a setting on the administrative console.  Look at your App Server configuration for the "modules" config item.  It is currently set to file system, right?  Change it to the database that has your modules.